# Need to modify this onlinejs code (internet detection script) to fire manually, not on a timer

Tags: javascript

I am using the excellent onlinejs (https://github.com/PixelsCommander/OnlineJS) library for checking that my app has a live internet connection. However, I don't need it to fire regularly, but rather upon the manual calling of the main function.

I would like to modify this code so that it is not firing on a timer, and know the name of the function to call for manual firing, which assume is just getterSetter.

My previous attempts to modify the code below have broken the script as I'm no expert at JavaScript. I appreciate any help in adapting this very useful code.

```
    function getterSetter(variableParent, variableName, getterFunction, setterFunction) {
    if (Object.defineProperty) {
        Object.defineProperty(variableParent, variableName, {
            get: getterFunction,
            set: setterFunction
        });
    }
    else if (document.__defineGetter__) {
        variableParent.__defineGetter__(variableName, getterFunction);
        variableParent.__defineSetter__(variableName, setterFunction);
    }
}

(function (w) {
    w.onlinejs = w.onlinejs || {};

    //Checks interval can be changed in runtime
    w.onLineCheckTimeout = 5000;

    //Use window.onLineURL incapsulated variable
    w.onlinejs._onLineURL = "http://lascelles.us/wavestream/online.php";

    w.onlinejs.setOnLineURL = function (newURL) {
        w.onlinejs._onLineURL = newURL;
        w.onlinejs.getStatusFromNavigatorOnLine();
    }

    w.onlinejs.getOnLineURL = function () {
        return w.onlinejs._onLineURL;
    }

    getterSetter(w, 'onLineURL', w.onlinejs.getOnLineURL, w.onlinejs.setOnLineURL);


    //Verification logic
    w.onlinejs.setStatus = function (newStatus) {
        w.onlinejs.fireHandlerDependOnStatus(newStatus);
        w.onLine = newStatus;
    }

    w.onlinejs.fireHandlerDependOnStatus = function (newStatus) {
        if (newStatus === true && w.onLineHandler !== undefined && (w.onLine !== true || w.onlinejs.handlerFired === false)) {
            w.onLineHandler();
        }
        if (newStatus === false && w.offLineHandler !== undefined && (w.onLine !== false || w.onlinejs.handlerFired === false)) {
            w.offLineHandler();
        }
        w.onlinejs.handlerFired = true;
    };

    w.onlinejs.startCheck = function () {
        setInterval("window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true)", w.onLineCheckTimeout);
    }

    w.onlinejs.stopCheck = function () {
        clearInterval("window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true)", w.onLineCheckTimeout);
    }

    w.checkOnLine = function () {
        w.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(false);
    }

    w.onlinejs.getOnLineCheckURL = function () {
        return w.onlinejs._onLineURL + '?' + Date.now();
    }

    w.onlinejs.getStatusFromNavigatorOnLine = function () {
        if (w.navigator.onLine !== undefined) {
            w.onlinejs.setStatus(w.navigator.onLine);
        } else {
            w.onlinejs.setStatus(true);
        }
    }

    //Network transport layer
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    w.onlinejs.isXMLHttp = function () {
        return "withCredentials" in xmlhttp;
    }

    w.onlinejs.isXDomain = function () {
        return typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined";
    }

    //For IE we use XDomainRequest and sometimes it uses a bit different logic, so adding decorator for this
    w.onlinejs.XDomainLogic = {
        init: function () {
            xmlhttp = new XDomainRequest();
            xmlhttp.onerror = function () {
                xmlhttp.status = 404;
                w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus();
            }
            xmlhttp.ontimeout = function () {
                xmlhttp.status = 404;
                w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus();
            }
        },
        onInternetAsyncStatus: function () {
            try {
                xmlhttp.status = 200;
                w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus();
            } catch (err) {
                w.onlinejs.setStatus(false);
            }
        },
        checkConnectionWithRequest: function (async) {
            xmlhttp.onload = w.onlinejs.logic.onInternetAsyncStatus;

            var url = w.onlinejs.getOnLineCheckURL();

            xmlhttp.open("GET", url);
            w.onlinejs.tryToSend(xmlhttp);
        }
    }

    //Another case for decoration is XMLHttpRequest
    w.onlinejs.XMLHttpLogic = {
        init: function () {

        },
        onInternetAsyncStatus: function () {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState === 4) {
                try {
                    w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus();
                } catch (err) {
                    w.onlinejs.setStatus(false);
                }
            }
        },
        checkConnectionWithRequest: function (async) {
            if (async) {
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = w.onlinejs.logic.onInternetAsyncStatus;
            } else {
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = undefined;
            }

            var url = w.onlinejs.getOnLineCheckURL();
            xmlhttp.open("HEAD", url, async);
            w.onlinejs.tryToSend(xmlhttp);

            if (async === false) {
                w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus();
                return w.onLine;
            }
        }
    }

    if (w.onlinejs.isXDomain()) {
        w.onlinejs.logic = w.onlinejs.XDomainLogic;
    } else {
        w.onlinejs.logic = w.onlinejs.XMLHttpLogic;
    }

    w.onlinejs.processXmlhttpStatus = function () {
        var tempOnLine = w.onlinejs.verifyStatus(xmlhttp.status);
        w.onlinejs.setStatus(tempOnLine);
    }

    w.onlinejs.verifyStatus = function (status) {
        return status === 200;
    }

    w.onlinejs.tryToSend = function (xmlhttprequest) {
        try {
            xmlhttprequest.send();
        } catch(e) {
            w.onlinejs.setStatus(false);
        }
    }

    //Events handling
    w.onlinejs.addEvent = function (obj, type, callback) {
        if (window.attachEvent) {
            obj.attachEvent('on' + type, callback);
        } else {
            obj.addEventListener(type, callback);
        }
    }

    w.onlinejs.addEvent(w, 'load', function () {
        w.onlinejs.fireHandlerDependOnStatus(w.onLine);
    });

    w.onlinejs.addEvent(w, 'online', function () {
        window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true);
    })

    w.onlinejs.addEvent(w, 'offline', function () {
        window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true);
    })

    w.onlinejs.getStatusFromNavigatorOnLine();
    w.onlinejs.logic.init();
    w.checkOnLine();
    w.onlinejs.startCheck();
    w.onlinejs.handlerFired = false;
    })(window);
```

Comment: an easy edit would be the `w.onlinejs.startCheck` function simply add a bool in there to enable kicking off the "timer" or `setInterval`

Comment: w.onlinejs.startCheck = function () {
        setInterval("window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true)", w.onLineCheckTimeout);......How would I add the boolean value to this as you describe?
    }

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the source, I believe you can simply call `onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(false)` to get the status synchronously. This function will return either `true` or `false`.

PS: I am sure there are better libraries for this task out there, I really do not like the way it's written and clearly, the author doesn't know JS very well. E.g., the following code taken from the library makes no sense at all.

```
w.onlinejs.stopCheck = function () {
        clearInterval("window.onlinejs.logic.checkConnectionWithRequest(true)", w.onLineCheckTimeout);
}
```